# AWS EC2, Tomcat7, Spring Boot, web, mvc, REST - http get method is not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I have developed "hello-world" web application using Spring Boot and locally (on embedded Tomcat) it works fine.

But when I uploaded my WAR file to Tomcat7 installed on AWS EC2 I have problems with invoking my simple http get methods - I am getting GET http:/ /my_server_address:8080/ping 404 (Not Found).

All static resources works ok (html, css files).

My Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
public class PingController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ping() {
    return "Live!";
}
}
```

My main class looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ServletInitializer.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServletInitializer.class, args);
}
}
```

I assume that I have problem with DispatcherServlet? I don't have web.xml - only simple application.properties

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right that you have an issue with `DispatcherServlet`. But more correctly to say, you have an issue with Spring Context.

When application is run via Spring Boot then Spring Boot cares about Spring Context and component scans.

If you want to run Spring MVC application with Tomcat you have to configure Spring Application Context manually either via XML or Java Base configuration. If you don't want to use `web.xml` you may use 'Full Java Base' configuration with [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) (You're using Tomcat 7, so it supports Servlet API 3.0)

By the way, in any way I suggest you to create `web.xml` to run Java Web Application in Java Web Server like the Tomcat.

Please, loot in [Spring MVC documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-introduction) to find more information.

Comment: Really thanks for your answer! I have realized that I don't need to install Tomcat - running my application as Spring Boot app will be enough. So I have changed packaging to 'jar' and used 'java -jar myjar.jar' to run :)